# Hash Url Extract to php

Tags: php, http, url

I want to be able to get hash parameters variable from client side URL and send to server and store in session for echo later in php

URL format in client side Browser:

domain.com/Betatest/#response_uri=https%3a%2f%2flogin.online.com%2ferror%3fcode%3d700AB8&state=email%40domain.com

I want to get the variable of state which is email%40domain.com encoded and uncoded means email@domain.com

I want to get the variable and save to session then echo later the variable using php

Answer (score 2):

Hash values are not sent to the server in a HTTP request. You need to put your data in the querystring, not hash, e.g.

```
domain.com/Betatest/?response_uri=https%3a%2f%2flogin.online.com%2ferror%3fcode%3d700AB8&state=email%40domain.com
```

That will give you two parameters (`response_uri` and `state`) which you can find in the PHP `$_GET` array, e.g. `$_GET["response_uri"]` and `$_GET["state"]`

Comment: It’s a return url with fragment which I can’t change. So I have to capture the variable from the client side and pass to server

Comment: Why can't you change it? What code is creating that hash? It seems whoever designed that made a bit of a mistake by using the hash.

Comment: If you really are stuck with this odd URL then you can get the hash value trivially using window.location.hash in JavaScript and use it to construct a URL more like the one I've shown, and send that to the server

Comment: Like I said it’s a return url with fragment which is only the client side understand and can see but I need the info extracted and pass along to server. 
I used Document.write(location.hash) in console and I got the hash parameters but I need to find out how I can extract the variable with JavaScript and declare it in php then echo

Comment: `Like I said`...yes and I asked you to clarify why you can't change it, which you haven't done, you've just repeated yourself instead. It looks so much like a querystring that it seems to me the creator just made a silly mistake and should have put a ? instead of # at the start. So maybe the solution is just to get that changed.

Comment: Anyway literally just take the hash, put a ? in front of it so it's a querystring and append it to the URL and send (via Ajax if need be). Then you can extract the state value from it as per my answer

Comment: Well, it’s a valid url which just happen to have fragment and I can’t change the url because it’s a redirect url from an open ID authentication

Comment: Ok well then you need to do as per my last comment